# Equivalent to torch.rfft() in newest PyTorch version

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, fft

I want to estimate the fourier transform for a given image of size `BxCxWxH`

In previous torch version the following did the job:

```
fft_im = torch.rfft(img, signal_ndim=2, onesided=False)
```

and the output was of size:

```
BxCxWxHx2
```

However, with the new version of rfft :

```
fft_im = torch.fft.rfft2(img, dim=2, norm=None)
```

I do not get the same results. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few issues

1. The `dim` argument you provided is an invalid type, it should be a tuple of two numbers or should be omitted. Really PyTorch should raise an exception. I would argue that the fact this ran without exception is a bug in PyTorch (I opened a ticket stating as much).
2. PyTorch now [supports `complex` tensor types](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/complex_numbers.html), so FFT functions return those instead of adding a new dimension for the real/imaginary parts. You can use [`torch.view_as_real`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.view_as_real.html#torch.view_as_real) to convert to the old representation. Also worth pointing out that `view_as_real` doesn't copy data since it returns a view so shouldn't slow things down in any noticeable way.
3. PyTorch no longer gives the option of disabling one-sided calculation in RFFT. Probably because disabling one-sided makes the result identical to `torch.fft.fft2`, which is in conflict with the 13th aphorism of PEP 20. The whole point of providing a special real-valued version of the FFT is that you need only compute half the values for each dimension, since the rest can be inferred via the Hermition symmetric property.

So from all that you should be able to use

```py
fft_im = torch.view_as_real(torch.fft.fft2(img))
```

**Important** If you're going to pass `fft_im` to other functions in `torch.fft` (like `fft.ifft` or `fft.fftshift`) then you'll need to convert back to the complex representation using [`torch.view_as_complex`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.view_as_complex.html#torch.view_as_complex) so those functions don't interpret the last dimension as a signal dimension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Following your solution, I still do not get a result of BxCxHxWx2 as expected. I rather get an output dimension BxCxHx(w/2).

Comment: @singa1994 I took a closer look at your question and realized I missed some parts. Rewrote the answer, hope this helps.